# Unable to send email with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am a novice to CI and PHP. Currently I'm using xammp to run PHP, Apache and MySql. Now I am trying to send an email with CI. But I constantly got an error as below.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond. )
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1689

I have google about three hours and still not found the solution. I have already enabled '`openssl`' in Apache. I would like to describe coding for my Email Controller Class.

//Code of Email Controller 'Index' function

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = "something@gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxx";

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('something@gmail.com', 'NayLinAung');
    $this->email->to('something@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('This is an email test');
    $this->email->message("It is working, Great! You will be successful.");

    if ($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "Email was successfully sent.";
    }
    else {  
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

When I change 'smtp' to 'mail', errors are not occurred but the email was not actually sent. In addition, I shutdown my Windows firewall.

Please, suggest any solutions for this error.

Comment: Have you tried smtp.gmail.com instead? Also, sometimes Gmail blocks your account and you are only able to send e-mail again if you try to login to your Gmail account using the site, then it will require a Captcha, after you login successfully all is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found earlier is:

To use Google SMTP in CodeIgniter you need to make 2 (two) changes into your Gmail account setting: *(N.B. Please be aware that it is now easier for an attacker to break into your account -says Google)*

> 1. Set off **2-step Verification**.
> 2. **Allow less secure apps**: ON (or Enable)

Now use `'smtp_host'` as `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` instead of `smtp.googlemail.com`

This issue also discussed in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909913/send-email-with-google-account-using-codeigniter/33784272#33784272).

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use 
try with this **IMAP** library

[Codeigniter Imap Library](https://github.com/iwatllc/CI_Imap)

you can connect with this code

```
$config['protocol'] = "imap";
$config['imap_host'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$config['imap_user'] = 'user@domain.com';
$config['imap_pass'] = 'Jk98S**Jlk';
$config['imap_port'] = '993';
$config['imap_mailbox'] = 'INBOX';
$config['imap_path'] = '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert'; // use this string if you do not want use ssl
$config['imap_server_encoding'] = 'utf-8';
$config['imap_attachemnt_dir'] = './tmp/';
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from($frommail);
$this->email->to($tomail);
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

you can use also **SMTP**
but if you have permition
 I advise you to use **IMAP**.
it have more functions and it is newer than **SMTP**...