# Send email with Google account using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I'm trying to send emails with CodeIgniter using `smtp.googlemail.com`. No problems with code but Google is preventing me from sending that email - here's the email I received on my Google account:

> A third party recently tried to use an application to connect to your
>   Google account.
>
> We blocked the connection attempt in case it would be a hacker trying
>   to access your account.
>
> If you have not made ​​this connection attempt, it may mean a third
>   party is trying to access your account. We recommend that you log into
>   your account and reset your password immediately. We blocked the
>   connection attempt in case it would be a hacker trying to access your
>   account.
>
> If this is your account and if you are having trouble to get there,
>   follow the troubleshooting procedure explained at
>   http://support.google.com/mail?p=client_login.

I have followed the link and didn't find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure this is an authentic message?  The grammar is incorrect in some places, and the writing style does not seem very Google-like.

Comment: The writing style seems unprofessional, and not to the standards which google have.. Whats the from address? are you sure this is a real message.. because I highly doubt it is

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, got an email from Google saying "Sign-in attempt prevented" when I was trying the same. I am ignoring what you have received from google and the text of email. Finally I solved the issue to send mail using CodeIgniter Email library today.

To use Google SMTP in CodeIgniter you need to make 2 (two) changes into Gmail account setting: *(N.B. Please be aware that it is now easier for an attacker to break into your account -says Google)*

> 1. Set off **2-step Verification**.
> 2. **Allow less secure apps**: ON (or Enable)

Now use `'smtp_host'` as `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` instead of `smtp.googlemail.com`

Hope this help.

Comment: Great answer. I just wanted to add that these settings are under My Account -> Sign-In & security.  I wasted some time looking for them in the Gmail settings and they aren't there.